# Make search bar in bootstrap navbar flush with borders of navbar

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm building a bootstrap WP theme and am at the stage of just building the static html. I've tried googling, but since it's hard to describe I've not had any luck. To simplify things, instead of telling you what I'm trying to do, I'll show you via very bad photoshop mockups and hopefully we can do some good together :).

I'm using the navbar snippet from http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

At the moment, it looks like this:

[image]

I want it to look like this:

[image]

ive tried playing with the paddings and the margins but am coming up blank. Any help is appreciated :).

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: add custom css to search bar and button, make it larger as it fits the background and remove the border-radius

Comment: thanks for your interest i see what I was not doing with the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.navbar-form{
margin-top:0px;
margin-bottom:0px;  
}
.navbar-form input{
min-height:50px;
border-radius:0;
}
.navbar-form button{
min-height:50px;
border-radius:0;
background:green;
color:white;    
}
```

Comment: that worked quite well with just a drag and drop. thank you very much :)